# How to break at first instruction of a program in visual studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I would like to tell Visual Studio to break at the first instruction of a program (before the `main()` function is called). I remember being able to do this in CodeWarrior IDE for embedded development, is this possible in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug + New Breakpoint + Break at Function.  Use wmainCRTStartup if you compile with Unicode support enabled, drop the w if you don't.  You'll be stepping through the CRT initialization code from there.